# SQL Server Version Verification Using Query

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to verify the SQL server version meet the minimum requirement with SQL query?

Something looks like:

```
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 4)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your SQL statement will throw an error except in a particular version then you won't be able to send it up without it erroring. You could check the version first with `SELECT @@VERSION` then based on that response, send your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SELECT @@VERSION` or `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')`.
Put this `SELECT` inside an IF-statement to conditionally run some logic.

The following webpage will give you some more advice: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/

Like:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '8%' THEN 'SQL2000'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '9%' THEN 'SQL2005'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '10.0%' THEN 'SQL2008'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '10.5%' THEN 'SQL2008 R2'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '11%' THEN 'SQL2012'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '12%' THEN 'SQL2014'
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '13%' THEN 'SQL2016'     
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '14%' THEN 'SQL2017' 
     ELSE 'unknown'
  END AS MajorVersion,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel,
  SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, applications should be checking database compat level rather than server level. This link explains further: < https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database>